# SQL : Filtering data using multiple column

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if this query is already asked, but i searched and can't find anything that resolve my issue.

I have two tables:

Table1:

```
Act       Marks   
Paint       6   
Paint       7       
Paint       16      
Paint       17  
Swim        6
Swim        2
Sea        448
Sea         17
Drama       6
Drama       7
Drama      16
```

Table 2:

```
Marks   Service_cordinator
  6            X3
  7            A2
  16            A3
  17             X1
  1              X2
  2              X3
  448            X4
  234            X5
```

Query is to fetch all the Acts which has service coordinator X3,A2, and A3. 
i.e. query should return `Paint` and `Drama`

There is no primary key / foregin key relationship in table. Only relation is `Marks` which is common among both table.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, and thank you for supplying sample data, but please note this is not a free coding service. You are expected to show a query that you have tried. If you then have difficulties with that query then ask for assistance on that query.  You need only to join the 2 tables using marks as the common data, then filter that by Service_cordinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `marks` to join the tables and then `group by` and `having`:

```
select t1.act
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.marks = t2.marks
where t2.Service_cordinator in ('X3', 'A2', 'A3')
group by t1.act
having count(distinct Service_cordinator) = 3;
```